# Running Application

Tags: android, api, kotlin

I have trouble on running app called belajar in Android Studio. From using:

1. activity_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="Belajar"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/black"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_home"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="gone"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_home"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

2. HomeActivity.xml:

```
package id.kotlin.belajar

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import id.kotlin.belajar.NetworkProvider.providesHttpAdapter
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response


class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        val progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.pb_home)

        val dataSource = providesHttpAdapter().create(HomeDataSource::class.java)
        dataSource.discoverMovie().enqueue(object : Callback<HomeResponse>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<HomeResponse>, response: Response<HomeResponse>) {
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

                val company = response.body()?.company
                val itemAdapter = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_home)
                itemAdapter.addItemDecoration(
                    DividerItemDecoration(
                        this@HomeActivity,
                        DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
                    )
                )
                itemAdapter.adapter = HomeAdapter(company ?: emptyList())

            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<HomeResponse>, t: Throwable){
                Log.e(HomeActivity::class.java.simpleName, "${t.printStackTrace()}")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

But I got an error when running the app:

```
2022-04-01 13:35:50.652 7386-7386/id.kotlin.belajar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: id.kotlin.belajar, PID: 7386
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{id.kotlin.belajar/id.kotlin.belajar.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 16 to dimension: type=0x1
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:720)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4190)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:654)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:650)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at id.kotlin.belajar.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I need help to fix this. This is my first time using kotlin for Android Studio. And this my training for developing my skill. Anybody can discuss with me using skype. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ConstraintLayout`. Make sure you need to use its property. Example here:

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Below full example:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_home"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: You mean I need to give numbers on the layout?

Comment: @WibisonoJanuar give numbers? I don't understand

Comment: 16 dp or 17 sp?

Comment: @WibisonoJanuar 16dp